# Instanstiate an object named empObject

Tags: vba

Assume that you have a class called Employee that has FirstName and LastName as its properties. Write code to instantiate object named empObject and set its first name to "Peter" and last name to "Johns"

public class Enployee

Answer (score -1):

```
class Employee {
     constructor(firstName, lastName){
         this.firstName = firstName;
         this.lastName = lastName;
     }
}

const empObject = new Employee('Peter', 'Johns');
```

This is how it is done in Javascript.

Comment: I believe the OP was asking about how to use VBA to do it.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I did not pay attention to that.